# How to add scroll in modalpanel?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have a modal panel which contains the dynamically included page. The page contains search form. After click the search button it shows the contents.

Intially the page height is less than 300px. After search the page height is more than 600px. So i cannot set the height statically. At that time of search the modalpanel partial contents are hide in the browser. So i need to put the scrollbar when the page is larger than browser.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

define

```
<style>
.scroll_div{
 overflow: scroll;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
</style>
```

and apply

```
<rich:modalPanel id="panel" width="350" height="100">
 <div class="scroll_div">
```

Source :http://community.jboss.org/message/66213

**Or**

override the css modal panel

```
.rich-mpnl-panel {
    position: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jigar,Thx for your quick reply.But if i put height="100" i restrict the height of the modalpanel.But i need to get the scroll without restrict the height of the modal panel.Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

it work for me by this code:

```
    .dr-mpnl-pnl {
        overflow: auto !important
    }
```

and add this component:

```
<rich:componentControl for="dynadetailModalPanel"
    attachTo="showPanelButton" operation="show" event="onclick" />

<rich:modalPanel id="dynadetailModalPanel" height="500" width="500" >
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

add required height and set over flow as scroll to the rich modalPanel in style.

```
<rich:modalPanel style="height:600px;overflow:scroll;">
```